# WIndows 8.1 drive letters assigning

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I have 2 storage devices: recently bought 250GB SSD (Samsung, drive0, 2 partitions) and 2TB HDD (WD, 2 partitions, drive1). Every time I install windows 8.1 on the SSD (drive0, part1) the drive letters get mixed like:

```
C: drive0 part1
D: drive1 part1
E: drive0 part2
F: drive1 part2
```

What I was expecting to see is:

```
C: drive0 part1
D: drive0 part1
E: drive1 part2
F: drive1 part2
```

I installed windows several times now, deleted partitions and repartitioned both drives with same "unexpected/bad" result. Can someone explain why is this happening or how to do to get the desired result?

Answer (score -1):

If your system partition is drive 0 part1 you should be able to change the other the drive letters.

http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/137/~/how-to-change-the-drive-letter-assignment-in-windows-8,-7,-vista,-xp-or-2000

Comment: It would be nice if you quoted the material from that external website.